# Real time data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

Hello I wan't to know what's the best approach in dealing with real time data in Laravel.

I am creating a dashboard which will track the current hours the user is taken from the start when he login. This tracker will also update the database record for all the users that started their time. It will update multiple columns and multiple rows. This data should be updated every second because we need to follow the time.

Can we use something like a cron jobs? or we need a third party system like pusher, pubnub, etc.

I am also using vuejs on my app.

EDIT=====================

I already done implementing the logging of hours of each individual user. Now, what I want is to display all those current users signing on, with their current and updated time coming from the database

Comment: this is not suggestion site, show use what you've tried.

Comment: Updating the database every second without real need sounds overkill to me.

Comment: Hello @Phiter it is a real needs because there will be users that will watch the real time data. That users are supervisors of that particular user that is currently signing on.

Comment: @Webinion I already done implementing the logging of hours of each individual user. Now, what I want is to display all those current users signing on with their current and updated time coming from the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `broadcasting` alongside `Pusher` to achieve this.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting#presence-channels

Broadcasting allows you to create `channels` that fire events when a user joins or leaves the `channel`.

A simple method would be:

- Add the user to a `channel` when they log in or go to a specific page
- Store what time they joined the channel using something like a session variable or in the database or something
- When the user closes the page or logs out, they are automatically removed from the `channel` which fires an event
- Compare the time from when they joined to when they left to see how long they were logged in or on a specific page etc.

If you need to track the current session you could check when their last logged in time was from the session/database and compare the time difference

Comment: cool......................

Answer (score 1):

Most programming languages have strengths in specific tasks and weaknesses in other tasks,having said that I do not mean to say they are incapable. Php is a server side language that facilitates database access predominantly mysql database.

As everyone else has said, you would need a front end, generally javascript, to provide AJAX or Comet updates from the backend, which can be written in PHP, although there are better languages to write applications that generate JSON output.

The best possible solution may be noSQL based PHP SDK.

You may try Firebase realtime PHP SDK at 
http://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/realtime-database.html

Hope it will help you!
Thanks